# IBM Rational Application Developer Version 7.5 and WAS6.1

Tags: ibm-rad

I am trying to install IBM Rational Application Developer Version 7.5 after installtion i found that WebSphere Application Server configration is missing How I can default configure in build WebSphere Application Server in this RAD.

how I can configure WebSphere Application Server Test Enviornment (WTE) installation into IBM Rational Application Developer Version 7.5 ? please reply ASAP .

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the configuration is missing?

The test servers (WAS 6, WAS 6.1, WAS 7) are installed as separate installable packages through the IBM Installation Manager with RAD 7.5.

Answer (score 0):

During installation of RAD, did you check that you also want WAS installed?

If you did that, then something could have been messed up a bit.

First, check if WAS is really installed. Search for "startServer" in your RAD installation; it's the command for starting up WAS. If it's installed, you'll find that command. Start your WAS instance and during startup check its output. There you should see enough information about its configuration.

Using that information, in RAD, create a new server with parameters you saw during WAS startup.

If WAS is not installed, then you'll have to use IBM's Installation manager to check what's really installed.